# Can't see keychain passwords on another mac

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, data-synchronization, keychain, google-apps

I am syncing one of my keychains over Google Drive. Unfortunately things which I add on Snow Leopard I am unable to see on Mountain Lion.

1. Is it some common issue, which could be easily fixed?
2. Or can I fix it at least as make it visible on Mountain Lion?

I am syncing the keychains over Google Drive. I've considered the problem could be in the way Google Drive is syncing that, but it also happens when I copy it over Samba and replace the keychain on another machine.

Comment: Please provide more of an explanation of your problem. This is a very broad question.

Comment: @Mailo As you are willing to invest 50 points into this, please provide some more information. How do you sync the keychain, does it work the other way round, does it work if you copy the keychain file manually etc.?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of processes will keep the keychain open, and may not realize that it has been replaced by another keychain.  For example, right now I have

```
sudo lsof login.keychain 
Password:
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
CalendarA   500  ats  txt    REG    1,4   753764 14974132 login.keychain
ubd         949  ats  txt    REG    1,4   753764 14974132 login.keychain
Dashboard  8779  ats  txt    REG    1,4   753764 14974132 login.keychain
Safari    29631  ats  txt    REG    1,4   753764 14974132 login.keychain
NetAuthSy 29809  ats  txt    REG    1,4   753764 14974132 login.keychain
WebProces 29823  ats  txt    REG    1,4   753764 14974132 login.keychain
```

You may need to restart things when you replace the keychain, or make sure only to sync the keychain when logged out.  (Which won't work well with dropbox.)

You might want to investigate something else like [Keychain2Go](http://www.jinx.de/Keychain2Go.html) which knows about the contents of keychains and makes sure to sync in a fashion that works while other things have it open.

Comment: I understand, but both the computers were restarted many times while i experience the problem. I was trying Keychain2Go, but was unable to get my keychain there

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Mac has permissions issues.  WHile the transfer through Google Drive would strip the permissions like using an external drive would, it's not working, causing things not to properly be transferred.  I would start with repairing permissions on the transfer FROM mac.  Then verify the permissions are stripped when its on the new machine.